# How to get SQL Server Trigger errors in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, error-handling

I have an insert trigger in Microsoft SQL Server that raise an error in some situations. like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerName]
ON [dbo].[TableName]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  ...
  IF (some conditions)
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Error Message',16,10);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RETURN;
  END;
  ...
END;
```

I want to get the error in PHP. my php code is similar to this:

```
...
mssql_min_error_severity(1);
mssql_min_message_severity(1);
$query="INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (...) VALUES (...)"; //values satisfy the error condition
if (mssql_query($query))
  echo "No error";
else
  echo "Error occured.";
//result is: No error
```

I expect to get 'Error occured' but I get 'No error' and no row is inserted in the table due to the ROLLBACK command.
What can I do to get an error when I try to insert not allowed values to the table?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

```
function error_occured($errorno,$errorstr)
  {
  throw new Exception($errorstr);
  }
...
$error_rep=error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_error_handler("error_occured",E_ALL);
try
  {
  $result=mssql_query($query);
  }
catch (Exception $e)
  {
  $result=false;
  }
error_reporting($error_rep);
restore_error_handler();
...
```

But this solution don't seems to be a proper way.
I am searching for a better one.

Comment: did you solved this,  I'm looking for the same issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

include within a try catch

```
 try {
       //actions php
   }
  catch (Exception $e) {

        throw $e; //get raise from sql

  }
```

Comment: I tried 'try catch'. but it do not raise any error. Even if I set: ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL)

Comment: As I found, try catch acts on exceptions, not on errors or warnings.